# Does non-combat damage affect Commander damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-commander-damage

Do the effects of a Commander that deal (non-combat) damage, such as [Obzedat, Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Obzedat%2C%20Ghost%20Council), count towards Commander damage?

I have not been able to find whether or not it has to be, specifically, combat damage, or simply damage dealt by the Commander.

Answer (score 11):

[Per the official rules on mtgcommander.net](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php),

> If a player has been dealt 21 points of **combat damage** by a particular Commander during the game, that player loses a game.

"Combat damage" refers only to damage dealt in combat as a result of attacking and blocking; direct-damage abilities don't count. Note also that [Obzedat, Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Obzedat%2C%20Ghost%20Council)'s triggered ability doesn't *deal damage*: it simply causes your opponent to *lose life*.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules)

> 104.3j In a Commander game, a player that's been **dealt 21 or more combat damage** by the same Commander over the course of the game loses the game. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704. Also see rule 903.14)